# Standard File Naming Conventions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, naming-conventions, conventions

For a file containing the given class, SomeCoolClass, what would be the proper or standard filename?

```
 1. somecoolclass.rb
 2. some_cool_class.rb
 3. some-cool-class.rb
 4. SomeCoolClass.rb
```

or some other variation?

I noticed in the Ruby stdlib, versions 1, 2 and 3 are used.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

With just [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) (i.e. not Rails), naming is only a convention.  In [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) the [convention](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7) of using underscores is necessary (almost).

I think convention #2  `lowercase_and_underscore.rb` is more common and looks pretty good, though an article [Here](http://rails.learnhub.com/lesson/page/5028-ruby-coding-convention) says `lowercasenounderscore.rb` is the Ruby convention.

**Pick either** which ever convention is more common or which ever one you like more.  The most important thing is to **be consistent within a project**.

Comment: The word from Ruby Gems is to use underscores (a.k.a. box-cutting or snakes) for file names, and Gem names: [Consistent Naming](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#consistent-naming).

Comment: That article you cited for `lowercasenounderscore.rb` is old and I haven't seen anyone else claiming that as the convention. Underscores is almost universally the standard.

Answer (score 9):

I personally think the hyphen as word separator makes for maximum readability and typability in general, so I recommend that where possible (in some contexts, a hyphen can't be used, such as in identifiers in most languages).  One important thing to bear in mind is that the scheme you pick will have a bearing on the require statement that users will use with your lib, and you want to **avoid having a different gem name than library name**.

Bad

```
# gem install my_cool_lib
require 'my-cool-lib'

# gem install MyCoolLib
require 'my_cool_lib'
```

Good

```
# gem install my_cool_lib
require 'my_cool_lib'

# gem install my-cool-lib
require 'my-cool-lib'
```

Unfortunately, a small handful of libraries violate this simple usability rule.  Don't be one of those libraries.  :)

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend lower case characters with underscores (number 2 in your question). It's true that this naming scheme is the convention in Rails and not necessary in non-Rails projects. However, I would still stick to the Rails convention because most Ruby programmers are probably using Ruby exclusively for Rails anyway.

Comment: Not only that, but underscores are the convention for most testing tools, plugin interfaces, etc. as well.  (E.g., if you have a file `foo.rb` and a spec file at `spec/foo_spec.rb`, Autotest will run the latter when the former changes, and many text editors will have shortcuts to jump between the two.)

Answer (score 5):

```
my-proj
├── README
├── lib
│   └── some_cool_class.rb
└── test
    └── some_cool_class_test.rb
```

Comment: Gemfile also goes at the top level if using Bundler or Rails